# php comparison operators on objects within loops

Tags: php, object, loops, comparison-operators

I have two arrays in php that contain custom class objects. One I iterate through in a while loop, using $h, and the other I access through another variable, $i, inside the while loop for comparison. I only increment $i within the parent loop if a certain condition is met, and there may be multiple copies of the same object within the array, which I need to skip over.

My code looks as follows:

```
$h = 0;
$i = 0
$j = 10; // Number determined elsewhere but statically entered for example purposes

while ($h < $j)
{
    if ($audits[$i]->id == $auditIDs[$h])
    {
        // Do Stuff...

        do
        {
            $i++;
        } while ($audits[$i]->id == $audits[$i+1]->id);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
    $h++;
}
```

If I replace the == comparison operator with === it still fails. Replace the do-while loop with a simple IF statement works, however.

```
if ($audits[$i]->id == $audits[$i+1]->id)
{
    $i++;
}
```

But that code does not allow for the possibility of more than one duplicate in the array, which may or may not occur, and I have to increment $i manually before calling the if statement (it must be incremented at least once if the previous if statement evaluates to true).

Can anyone shed some light into the situation? I appreciate the help!

```
class auditItem
{
    public $login;
    public $points;
    public $date;
    public $onTime;
    public $name;
    public $id;
    public $msg;

    function auditItem($login, $points, $date, $name, $id, $msg)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->points = $points;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, the do-while loop has special behavior. It differs from a regular while loop in the fact that the first iteration is guaranteed to always run. In your code, $i has already been incremented by 1 before the comparison check, whereas, in the if statement, it has not.

That's the difference in the two blocks of code I noticed. You haven't given enough information about the $audits array to provide a solid solution. Perhaps the the second index is out of bounds?

Comment: Your comment got me thinking about the out of bounds -- I just wrapped the do-while loop in an if statement 
`if (isset($audits[$i+1])) {}`
and now it works beautifully. Thanks gluxon!

Comment: Glad to help! Nice to know I was somewhat close ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a while loop instead of do-while? In that case the condition will be first evaluated at $i=0 and incremented afterwards.

Comment: If the first IF statement is true, then $i needs to be incremented at least once. My problem is that if there are two objects with the same ID, I need to increment $i until I reach the last object in that array with that ID.